# Standard Settings for UILabel in MKAnnotation Callout Bubble

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, mkannotationview, callouts

I am showing customized Callout Bubbles with the help of this tutorial [tutorial](http://dev.tuyennguyen.ca/?p=298)

If I show a custom Callout Bubble I add a view Labels into that bubble and I want them to look exactly like the standard ones.
So does anybody know the settings like font, size, shadowColor, shadowOffset and stuff like that for both the title and the subtitle Label?

Or where I could find them?